# not getting proper address using latitude-longitude

Tags: google-maps

I went to http://maps.google.co.in/ ,there I typed **restaurants near Mexico** in search bar,I press Enter,it shows me list of restuarant,For e.g. I clicked on first restuarant '`La Palapa Restaurant`' after that clicked on `more` then clicked on `Send` ,it opens a Frame then I clicked link `La Palapa Restaurant` from the Frame.From that link I got latitude-longitude `&ll=25.958045,-98.349609&spn=21.866133,43.022461`.
   I am getting the different address using this latitude-longitude `25.958045,-98.349609`, And in that Frame I have another address.There is a address mismatch.I went through these two sites to confirm the address. 
   http://www.findlatitudeandlongitude.com/find-address-from-latitude-and-longitude.php and http://itouchmap.com/latlong.html.
   Please guide me,how to solve this issue.Is there need to convert these latitude-longitude to get the proper address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters for the iframe-URL doesn't contain any informations about the markers(places), the ll-parameter e.g.  defines the center of the map(see http://www.seomoz.org/ugc/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-google-maps-parameters), so you can't use them to get any details related to the place.

The LatLng for this particular place would is `20.599526,-105.238832`

To get details for places programmatically request the [places-service](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#TextSearchRequests)

Comment: Thank You, Dr.Molle.There is also spn in this URL.Can we make any calculation for this or any formula to convert these latitude-longitude [25.958045,-98.349609] to get informations about the markers(places).